# Sistema de inventario con seriales y lotes en c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

Buen día,

Tengo una duda con un sistema de inventario que estoy desarrollando.

Tengo productos médicos que consisten en una misma Marca, pero que se deben agrupar por su SERIAL o LOTE.

***Un ejemplo: un mismo modelo de telefono, pero con distintos IMEI.***

Mi problema es, como manejar la entrada, salida y stock de un mismo modelo, pero a traves de sus seriales o lotes?

No consigo como hacer que cada vez que ingrese un mismo producto, me lo catalogue como uno solo y no como uno nuevo.

Gracias.

Comment: Comparte lo que has logrado hasta ahora

Comment: Yo usaría una tabla para los productos y otra para los lotes con la cantidad que entra o sale y controlar el stock